# Xcode: change font in variables view

Tags: xcode, font-size

The font in the variables view of the debugger is super tiny. Is there a way to enlarge it? Thanks.

I can't find a way to set it in Preferences -> Fonts and Colors, either on Source or Console.

I mean the part in the lower left in this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I'm afraid you can't. It's part of the standard UI of Xcode, not the editor or the console.
The only way to make those bigger is to change the display resolution.

Comment: That's such a strange oversight on Apple's part.  It's such an obvious need for most developers over 40.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this? I could change the font by clicking the little "T"icon at the bottom part of the "Preference --- Fonts & Colors --- Console" interface. Please see the picture[image]

[image]

Comment: No, that's the console. The variable view is where it shows you all the variables currently in scope, and all their values. I added a picture.